# Asymptotic equivalence of sum of arithmetic function

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

> Let $f$ be an arithmetic function such that $\sum_{n \leq N} f(n) n^{-\frac{1}{2}} \sim N$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$. Prove that
>
> \begin{equation}
> \sum_{n \leq N} f(n) \sim \frac{2}{3} N^{\frac{3}{2}} \quad \text{ as } N \rightarrow \infty.
> \end{equation}

I have an issue with understanding how to solve such types of problem (perhaps someone can point me to some reference). I was thinking of applying Euler's Summation Formula, Summation by Parts (but they require that $f$ is $C^{1}$), and the Convolution Method. But I can't seem to proceed. Also how are such expressions of the form $\sum_{n \leq N} f(n) n^{-\frac{1}{2}} \sim N$ called? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Summation by parts shouldn't require that $f$ is differentiable in this case, only that $n^{1/2}$ is differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with a sum of terms $f(n)/\sqrt{n}$ is weird.  Call that $a_n$, so your task can be presented in a more elegant form: if $\sum_{n \leq N} a_n \sim N$ as $N \to \infty$ then $\sum_{n \leq N} a_n\sqrt{n} \sim (2/3)N^{3/2}$ as $N \to \infty$.  (Asymptotic relations below are understood to be taking place "as $N \to \infty$" so I won't repeat that each time.)

Intuitively, if $\sum_{n \leq N} a_n \sim N$ then we *imagine* this is because $a_n \sim 1$ (that would explain the hypothesis in a simple way), and with $a_n = 1$ we'd get $\sum_{n \leq N} a_n\sqrt{n} = \sum_{n \leq N} \sqrt{n} \sim (2/3)N^{3/2}$, so the conclusion looks *plausible*. Do you agree that $\sum_{n \leq N} n^\alpha \sim N^{\alpha+1}/(\alpha+1)$ when $\alpha > -1$, or at least when $\alpha > 0$?

Aim for a broader result than your task: if $\sum_{n \leq N} a_n \sim N$ then $\sum_{n \leq N} a_nn^\alpha \sim N^{\alpha+1}/(\alpha+1)$ when $\alpha > 0$. Your task is the case $\alpha = 1/2$. All you need for this is summation by parts (why do you say summation by parts requires a function is $C^1$?) *plus* the following property of asymptotic partial sums: if $b_n$ and $c_n$ are positive sequences with $b_n \sim c_n$ as $n \to \infty$ and $\sum_{n \leq N} b_n$ diverges (or $\sum_{n \leq N} c_n$ diverges) then $\sum_{n \leq N} b_n \sim \sum_{n \leq N} c_n$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Probably confusing with Abel summation formula

Comment: @reuns Yes, it seems that my lecture notes calls summation by parts what is actually Abel's summation formula.